# Booting multiple Windows 7 from same image and then applying correct CD key

Tags: windows-7, boot, product-key, iscsi

I'm planning to connect 21 Windows 7 computers (OEM) to a central server with iSCSI, and then boot all computers from the same "image".

The problem is the CD key. I have 21 valid OEM keys with valid activations on them all.
Is there any way to "load" an activation during boot? Or apply a CD key during boot, and then load an activation file?

It's not a wise choice to do a full activation at each boot since Microsoft will think the key is stolen, even if it's activated on the same hardware all the time.

So basically, when PC1 boots from the image, it should in some way apply the CD key for PC1 on the computer and also load the activation file for PC1, and when PC2 boots from the image, it should apply key 2 & activation 2 and so on.

How can this be accomplished? Microsoft won't give us a VLK (Volume Key) since according to them, all VLK sales for Windows 7 are ended and only product purchasable is Windows 8.

Comment: I think you could try scripting with PowerShell. Here's a tip: slmgr -ipk XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX (this installs the new Product Key). NOTE: I'm not entirely sure if it work 100% with OEM keys....

Comment: Yes, it does work with slmgr. However, the activation needs to be done after each updating of key, and if we activate the same computer at each bootup (about 1-5 times/day), wonder what happens? Maybe microsoft will block the key as stolen. So, how can the activation be solved? Is theres some activation file somewhere containing the activation, that I can copy and store on the server, and then replace when slmgr has done its work?

Comment: I believe that once the activation is done it won't try to re-activate unless you make a significant hardware change to your computer, such as upgrading the hard disk and memory at the same time. [How Windows Product Activation (WPA) Works?](http://www.gohacking.com/how-windows-product-activation-works/) and [How does the new Windows Product Activation (WPA) scheme work?](http://www.yak.net/fqa/256.html)

Comment: Yes, but since the system will boot from a read-only image, the "activation information" (b) in the text file, will be lost, like a reformat was done. The question is where the information of a sucessful activation is stored, so I can copy that information to a writable medium via a start-up-script Before shutting down, and at each bootup, replace the activation information again, so the computer stay activated after initial activation. Note that ALL computers boot from the same read-only image, so its not a simple matter of "activating" the read-only image.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is not really possible with Windows 7 OEM licensing. You will want to purchase Windows 8 VLKs under an Open License Agreement, which will provide you downgrade rights to Windows 7. This is what we did at a place I worked recently. When you login to your License Portal, you will see you have a MAK for Win 7.

On Microsoft's site, you can read more about [downgrade rights](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/licensing/sblicensing/pages/downgrade_rights.aspx).

Comment: The problem is that it cost about 200$ per computer, and we cannot really afford it. They wont turn in the old OEM licenses either. They said that its not possible to purchase a "upgrade to windows 8" for the reason that Windows 7 needs to be installed and activated for a upgrade to be done, and thus it defeats the whole purpose of using VLKs. So basically, the only option was to buy new non-upgrade keys.

Comment: @sebastiannielsen, yep, that's the horrendous pain of MS licensing. :\ Sorry to hear it caused such trouble.